# Idiomatic expression for "moving away" from a subject

Tags: idioms

I am in a meeting with a lot of people but the person who is speaking is not focusing on the subject, that person is somehow "moving away" from what is really important.
Is there any expression for that mirrors that situation or any other words I can use to talk about it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Beating around the bush' seems to fit, as does 'diverging from the main topic', or maybe even 'off-topic' (the word we often see on SE!) depending on how far away the discussion is going.